# Frustrating favicon issue

Tags: favicon

I have a really frustrating problem because I can't find any solution to it. So about two weeks ago I uploaded a favicon to my site and now I decided I wanted to change it. So yeah, I upload the new one to replace the old one but even after doing this ten times over and over again and trying on different computers, and also trying creating a new favicon, and to be 100 % certain the problem isn't on me I used varios automated programs but still, my favicon doesn't update. Any idea what the problem can be? This feels too basic to be a problem for me but I really can't see what the problem is. At least it's not big problem as I can live without a favicon but of course it's frustrating when something this basic doesn't work. Btw, site is http://www.minepick.com

I have this markup inside the `head` element:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Where are you hosting the site?  I use Rackspace cloud and they do some pretty heavy content caching such that I have to force a site refresh by changing the name of the web.config file (it's a .NET environment).  Perhaps your hosting provider is doing something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure that you clear the cache on the browser of any PC that is viewing the site.

Make sure that no CDN's are in place that might be not updating as fast.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the old line with this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://{your-site}/favicon.ico?ver=2" />
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Usually unnecessary to add the domain. Most often, unbookmarking the site and clearing the cache will do it. Remember that most browsers do not ask for a fresh copy (update) of a favicon.ico for quite a long period -- certainly not on every page load.